# Twilio SMS - where to set the webhook for opt-outs?

Tags: api, twilio, webhooks

The Twilio Console is confusing me. I can't seem to find a location where I can set the URL that my webhook is at for managing Opt Outs to my SMS campaigns.

I'm using a Messaging Service, and I'm on the Integration page settings of that service. Here's the screenshot:
[image]

I want to set it to “Drop the Message” (so I won’t be billed for incoming messages) – but now I want to understand how I can manage my opt-out requests. How/Where can I set which URL webhook they should go to?

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For Long Codes and Toll Free Numbers, the Opt-in/Opt-out is handled by Twilio.

[Twilio support for opt-out keywords (SMS STOP filtering)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-)

Or if you enabled Advanced Opt-out

[Getting Started with Advanced Opt-Out for Messaging Services](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services)

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I'm afraid I don't see anything on those two pages that reference where in the Console I am meant to set where my Webhook gets sent to.

Comment: It is automatic, Twilio handles Opt-in/Opt-outs for LC's/TF's, "By default, Twilio handles standard English-language reply messages such as STOP, UNSTOP, UNSUBSCRIBE or CANCEL for Toll-Free and Long Code messages, in accordance with industry standards."

Comment: I am also just starting with Twilio SMS integration for our site. I think the confusing point that's not very clear is that apparently when selecting "Drop the message" and Twilio handles the opt-out (internal block list) they DO NOT send any notice at all to your backend to let you know an opt-out occurred. So there is no webhook you can set in that case. If I have that right.